# Function parameter in C not modified after function is called

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

double gen(double dS) //Function for a random double variable
{
    double dx=0;
    dx=rand()%200+1;
    dS=dx/100;
    return(dS);
}

int main()
{
    double dZahl=0;
    double dTokens=1;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    double dSummand=0;
    int iGame=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Deine Tokens:%.2lf\n", dTokens);  //This doesn't really matter
        printf("Was m%cchtest du tun?\n[1]:Generiere Tokens\n[2]:Spiele ein Minigame\n", 148);
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &iGame);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch (iGame)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                gen(dSummand);  //function in use
                dTokens=dTokens+dSummand;
                printf("\nDu hast %.2lf Tokens generiert!\n", dSummand);  //the output of the value
                fflush(stdout);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    getch();
}
```

The problem is that dSummand doesn't get the value from dS. Does anyone know what the problem is because I was trying to fix it but I couldn't figure it out.

I am trying to get a random double value with a function for my program. I thought it would work like this but unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: Please retitle your question so it reflects the subject of the problem rather than a plea for help. Also I doubt [tag:eclipse] is the correct tag. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value for `dS` to come out of the function modified you have to pass a pointer.

```
double gen(double *dS) {

*dS=dx/100;
```

and then

```
gen(&dSummand);
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now. Never thought of using a pointer.

Comment: Alternatively, use `double gen(void)` as the function interface and call `dS = gen();` — that would also work neatly.

Comment: Is this a copy by value issue?