# unload() of a hash table doens't seem to work

Tags: c, function, hash

The function below is supposed to unload my hash table `node* table[26];`. It returns true if the hash table is successfully unloaded, false if it didn't. But here, it keeps on returning false.
I don't what I did wrong .

```
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        free_table(table[i]);
        if (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


void free_table(node* hash)
{
    if (hash == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    free_table(hash -> next);
    free(hash);
    hash = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `table[i]` to become `NULL`?

Comment: @DavisHerring I have set hash to null in free_table() , and the fact that i'm passing table[i] to free_table()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function parameter in C not modified after function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536690/function-parameter-in-c-not-modified-after-function-is-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In This code

```
    free_table(table[i]);
    if (table[i] != NULL)
```

`table[i]` is not updated by free_table

If you want to update it you must do

```
   void free_table(node** hash);
   ...
   free_table(&table[i]);
   if (table[i] != NULL)
   ....
   void free_table(node** hash)
   {
      if (*hash == NULL)
      {
         return;
      }
      free_table((*hash) -> next);
      free(*hash);
      *hash = NULL;
}
```

ie - c style 'pass by reference' , aka 'double pointer'

Comment: I am getting this error whenever I compile :
```
error: incompatible pointer types passing 'node **' (aka 'struct node **') to parameter of type 'node *' (aka 'struct node *'); remove & [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        free_table(&table[i]);
                   ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You changed only some of the places that need changing.

Comment: I think I should be good to go, free_table() accepts a double pointer, but it gives error when I pass &table[i]. why ??

Comment: @AtmaneLee The errors clearly state that you did *not* change free_table to accept a double pointer.